# How to get data prior to one month of what user enters in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**current query**

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 where 
id=1234 and (date(sys_time) 
between "2015-07-01" AND "2015-07-10")
;
```

> I want to get the data prior to one month from the dates mentioned
>   here. Is there any SQL query to do it?

Comment: use [`date_sub`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: Prior to 2015-06-01?

Comment: yea prior to 2015-06-01

Answer (score 0):

Just use `date_sub()`:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table1 
WHERE id = 1234 AND 
      sys_time >= date_sub('2015-07-01', interval 1 month) and
      sys_time < date_add(date_sub('2015-07-01', interval 1 month), interval 1 day)
```

Notice that I removed the `date()` function from `sys_time`.  This helps MySQL use an index for the expression, if one is available:

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDate, DATEADD(dd,-30,getdate())
```

You could set the "current date" and the previous date as parameters and include those in your query as the critera

Answer (score 0):

Use  DATE_ADD("2015-07-03", INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  for  the  adding  interval

Example :

SELECT a,b FROM   table WHERE `from_date` between  DATE_ADD("2015-07-01", INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND DATE_ADD("2015-07-03", INTERVAL 1 MONTH)